# Defining multiple generic types in function argument in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

I am trying to use generics in Rust and have encountered
a probem when trying to define a function.

Let a method `get` take in a Vector where its type is generic, for example

```
fn get<T1: serde::Serialize, T2: serde::Serialize>(input: Vec<T>)
where T can be either T1 or T2
```

I am trying to define the function properly especially I am stuck at the point where I need to define T such that it can either be T1 or T2.

Is this possible in Rust?

Comment: Specifically about two types, there is the [`either`](https://docs.rs/either) crate that also implements a bunch of useful traits and methods.

Comment: The either crate seems to be useful. I will use it. Thanks!

Comment: You can simply define an enum that contains variants of these types, or define a trait an implement if for both. `T1` and `T2` seem to be the same in your example tho